# How to check Linux version with Autoconf?

Tags: linux, autoconf

My program requires at least Linux 2.6.26 (I use timerfd and some other Linux-specific features).

I have an general idea how to write this macro but I don't have enough knowledge about writing  test macros for Autoconf. Algorithm:

1. Run "uname --release" and store output
2. Parse output and subtract Linux version number (MAJOR.MINOR.MICRO)
3. Compare version

I don't know how to run command, store output and parse it.

Maybe such macro already exists and it's available (I haven't found any)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a macro for steps 2 (parse) and 3 (compare) version, [ax_compare_version](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_compare_version.html).  For example:

```
linux_version=$(uname --release)
AX_COMPARE_VERSION($linux_version, [eq3], [2.6.26],
    [AC_MSG_NOTICE([Ok])],
    [AC_MSG_ERROR([Bad Linux version])])
```

Here I used `eq3` so that if `$linux_version` contained additional strings, such as `-amd64`, the comparison still succeeds.  There is a plethora of comparison operators available.

Answer (score 6):

I think you'd be better off detecting the specific functions you need using `AC_CHECK_FUNC`, rather than a specific kernel version.
This will also prevent breakage if you find yourself cross-compiling at some point in the future

Comment: This will not work for me, because Linux function  accepts flags in functrion timerfd_settime() since version 2.6.26 and I can check this only at runtime.

Any other idea?

Comment: Do you mean it accepts certain flags in 2.6.26 that didn't exist before? you could check for the existence of those flags using `AC_CHECK_DECL`, and if all else fails, you can use `AC_RUN_IFELSE` to compile and run a test program to check for anything else that can really only be tested at run time

Comment: Yes, Linux supports flags in this function since version 2.6.26. AFAIR  on older kernels timerfd_settime() faield with EINVAL error, when any flags were used.
I will try to use AC_RUN_IFELSE as you suggested.

Comment: @Goofy (18 month old question may already be totally obsolete) Anything that "can only be done at runtime" can also be done at configure time.  If you need certain behavior from a function, you write a test which is invoked and check its output.  (When the configure script is run and the test is running, you are in "runtime")

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you not to check the Linux version number, but for the specific type you need or function. Who knows, maybe someone decides to backport `timerfd_settime()` to 2.4.x? So I think [`AC_CANONICAL_TARGET`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Canonicalizing.html) and [`AC_CHECK_LIB`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Libraries.html) or similar are your friends. If you need to check the function arguments or test behaviour, you'd better write a simple program and use `AC_LANG_CONFTEST([AC_LANG_PROGRAM(...)])`/`AC_TRY_RUN` to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Without going too deep and write autoconf macros properly (which would be preferable anyway) don't forget that configure.ac is basically a shell script preprocessed by m4. So you can write shell commands directly.

```
 # prev. part of configure.ac
 if test `uname -r |cut -d. -f1` -lt 2 then; echo "major v. error"; exit 1; fi
 if test `uname -r |cut -d. -f2` -lt 6 then; echo "minor v. error"; exit 1; fi
 if test `uname -r |cut -d. -f3` -lt 26 then; echo "micro error"; exit 1; fi
 # ...
```

This is just an idea if you want to do it avoiding writing macros for autoconf. This choice is not good, but should work...

The best way is the already suggested one: you should check for features; so, say in a future kernel timerfd is no more available... or changed someway your code is broken... you won't catch it since you test for version.

**edit**

As user foof says in comments (with other words), it is a naive way to check for major.minor.micro. E.g. 3.5.1 will fail because of 5 being lt 6, but 3.5.1 comes after 2.6.26 so (likely) it should be accepted. There are many tricks that can be used in order to transform x.y.z into a representation that puts each version in its "natural" order. E.g. if we expect x, y, or z won't be greather than 999, we can do something like multiplying by 1000000 major, 1000 minor and 1 micro: thus, you can compare the result with 2006026 as Foof suggested in comment(s).

Comment: Note that the sample code will break for major/minor version changes. :-) E.g. Linux kernel version 3.5.25 will fail two times. (You could simply combine the major, minor and micro versions into a single version number `v=$(uname -r | awk -F'[^[0-9]]*' '{print (1000000 * $1 + 1000 * $2 + $3) }')` and compare this `$v` against `2006026` for a little bit more robust test.)

Comment: Of course you are right. It was a cheap immediate example of how to add some test on those numbers. It should have be taken just as "tool demo", not "right usage" of the tools :) Going to add some words about

Comment: (Note that some kernel versions have micro version larger than 99 -  there used to be version 1.3.100  and 2.1.132 (see subdirectories of https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/). Your edited answer still works for *checking against 2.6.26*, but somebody reading your code needs to use extra thinking cycles remembering/suspecting the micro version overflow; also somebody might copy-paste the solution to a setting where it does not happen to work though it is of course unlikely anybody is seriously using such an old kernel version. I promise this is the last comment on the subject!)

Comment: I was in the mood of saving zeros:)